# Sound comes only after clicking on a specific tab in Angular 4

Tags: angular, audio, chat

I am making a multi user chat application using MEAN stack. For new incoming messages, I am playing sound using following code in Angular 4:

```
let audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "../../assets/sound/incoming-chat.mp3";
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

This method works for most of the time. But sometimes sound comes only after clicking on a specific tab where the Angular app is open.

Is it possible to play sound independent of which tab is active in the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a service for this task. And you can call a specific method the play the sound. After that you just have to call this method from any component and that's it.